# How to solve this equation of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

$$
F(X,Y)=(t_1^2+t_2^2+2t_1t_2X)^2Y^2-2t_3^2(t_1^2X+t_2^2X+2t_1t_2)Y+t_3^4
$$

I want to know the point $(X,Y)$ which satisfied with $F(X,Y)=0$.
Now, $t_1,t_2,t_3$ are positive numbers.

By numerical calculation, I noticed $F(1,(\frac{t_3}{t_1+t_2})^2)=0$ when $\frac{t_3}{t_1+t_2}<1$.

I want to know how to know this result analytically.
Is it possible??

Comment: `I want to know the point (X,Y)` What makes you think or expect that a single equation with two unknowns would have a unique solution?

Comment: @Sakurai.JJ: You claim
$$F(1,\frac{t_3}{t_1+t_2})=0$$
when 
$$\frac{t_3}{t_1+t_2}<1$$
but that doesn't seem to check, using, for example
$$t_1=t_2=t_3=1,\;X=1,\;Y=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @quasi Right. Let me try one more time: I think the OP may have meant $Y = t_3^2 / (t_1+t_2)^2\,$ instead. I got that right in the answer, but wrong for some reason in my previous (now deleted) comment.

Comment: @dxiv: Yes, that works. It can be seen at a glance by using $X=1$ in your posted formula for $Y$. Oh, just noticed -- you edited in that observation as well (but I saw it all by myself, without looking!).

Comment: @quasi Yes, or by substituting directly into the definition of $F$ and using that $t_1^2+t_2^2+2t_1t_2=(t_1+t_2)^2$: $$F(1,Y)=(t_1+t_2)^4Y^2- 2t_3^2(t_1+t_2)^2Y+t_3^4=\big((t_1+t_2)^2Y - t_3^2\big)^2$$

Comment: Thank you. I should have written $F(1,(\frac{t_3}{t_1+t_2})^2)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  consider $F$ as a quadratic in $Y$ and note that its reduced discriminant is:

$$
\frac{1}{4}\Delta = t_3^4 (t_1^2 X + t_2^2 X + 2 t_1 t_2)^2 - t_3^4(t_1^2+t_2^2+2t_1 t_2 X)^2=t_3^4 (t_1^2 - t_2^2)^2 (X^2 - 1)
$$

Therefore $\,F(X,Y)=(t_1^2+t_2^2+2t_1t_2X)^2(Y-Y_1)(Y-Y_2)\,$ where:

$$
Y_{1,2} = \frac{t_3^2(t_1^2X+t_2^2X+2t_1t_2) \pm t_3^2(t_1^2-t_2^2) \sqrt{X^2-1} \big/ 2}{(t_1^2+t_2^2+2t_1t_2X)^2}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  For $\,X=1\,$ the above reduces to $\,Y_1=Y_2=t_3^2 / (t_1+t_2)^2\,$ so:

$$
F(1,Y)=(t_1+t_2)^4\big(Y-t_3^2 / (t_1+t_2)^2\big)^2 = \big((t_1+t_2)^2 Y - t_3^2\big)^2
$$